# Try/catch block breaks asynchronous JS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have the following db calls

```
const x = await doThis();
cons y = await doThat(x);

return somethingElse(x,y)
```

This works fine but when a promise isn't returned correctly, debugging is impossible. I want to write code something like the following

```
  try {
    const x = await doThis();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  try {
    cons y = await doThat(x);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  return somethingElse(x,y);
```

However, I get the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Do the try/catch blocks stop the code from running asynchronously? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

When you declare variables with `let` or `const` they are *bracket-scoped*.

In you code part `x` and `y` are *bracket-scoped* to their `try` statements - so why they are not defined outside of `try`. You need to define them before `try` statements.

You can also replace `const` with `var`. This will hoist the variables declaration in the start of the function (based on the `return` statement that it is a function) and will work - `x` and `y` will be visible to whole function, but I recommend to use the approach with `let` declaration.

```
let x, y;

try {
   x = await doThis();
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}

try {
   y = await doThat(x);
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}

return somethingElse(x,y);
```

Comment: Ah, got it - I'll mark as correct when it let's me.

Comment: Or if you're lazy, could use `var` instead of `const` to hoist them to function scope. Good catch though, I didn't spot that at first.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with scoping. You declare x and y inside a try block so they are only scoped inside that block. Declare them outside the block and assign the values inside the try blocks. Keep in mind that the values could still be undefined if there is an exception in which case you should check for a value before proceeding to the next call.

```
let x, y;

try {
  x = await doThis();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

try {
  if(x) // check if x has a value, if there was an exception then x could be undefined
     y = await doThat(x);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

if(y) // check if y has a value, if there was an exception then y could be undefined
    return somethingElse(x,y);
return null;// or something else??
```

Comment: If you're using `var`, you technically don't need to move the declarations out of the `try/catch` blocks since `var` is a function scope declaration.